# Tightly coupled parallel class hierarchies in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, class-design

For context, I'm working on a C++ [artificial-life system](http://github.com/taliesinb/floatworld/) involving agents controlled by recurrent neural networks, but the details aren't important.

I'm facing a need to keep two object hierarchies for the "brain" and "body" of my agents separate. I want a variety of different brain and body types that can be coupled to each other at run-time. I need to do this to avoid a combinatorial explosion caused by the multiplicative enumeration of the separate concerns of *how a body works* and *how a brain works*.

For example, there are many topologies and styles of recurrent neural network with a variety of different transfer functions and input/output conventions. These details don't depend on how the body of the agent works, however, as long as sensory inputs can be encoded into neural activity and then decoded into actions.

Here is a simple class hierarchy that illustrates the problem and one potential solution:

```
// Classes we are going to declare

class Image2D; // fake
class Angle2D; // fake

class Brain;    
class Body;      
class BodyWithEyes;
class BrainWithVisualCortex;

// Brain and Body base classes know about their parallels

class Brain
{
  public:
    Body* base_body;

    Body* body() { return base_body; }
    virtual Brain* copy() { return 0; } // fake

    // ...etc
};

class Body
{
  public:
    Brain* base_brain;

    Brain* brain() { return base_brain; }
    virtual Body* reproduce() { return 0; } // fake

    // ...etc
};

// Now introduce two strongly coupled derived classes, with overloaded access
// methods to each-other that return the parallel derived type

class BrainWithVisualCortex : public Brain
{
  public:
    BodyWithEyes* body();
    virtual void look_for_snakes();
    virtual Angle2D* where_to_look_next() { return 0; } // fake
};

class BodyWithEyes : public Body
{
  public:
    BrainWithVisualCortex* brain();
    virtual void swivel_eyeballs();
    virtual Image2D* get_image() { return 0; } // fake
};

// Member functions of these derived classes

void BrainWithVisualCortex::look_for_snakes()
{
  Image2D* image = body()->get_image();

  // ... find snakes and respond
}

void BodyWithEyes::swivel_eyeballs()
{
  Angle2D* next = brain()->where_to_look_next();

  // ... move muscles to achieve the brain's desired gaze
}

// Sugar to allow derived parallel classes to refer to each-other

BodyWithEyes* BrainWithVisualCortex::body()  
{ return dynamic_cast<BodyWithEyes*>(base_body); }

BrainWithVisualCortex* BodyWithEyes::brain() 
{ return dynamic_cast<BrainWithVisualCortex*>(base_brain); }

// pretty vacuous test
int main()
{
  BodyWithEyes* body = new BodyWithEyes;
  BrainWithVisualCortex* brain = new BrainWithVisualCortex;
  body->base_brain = brain;
  brain->base_body = body;
  brain->look_for_snakes();
  body->swivel_eyeballs();
}
```

The trouble with this approach is that it's clunky and not particularly type-safe. It does have the benefit that the body() and brain() member functions provide a bit of sugar for derived classes to refer to their partners.

Does anyone know of a better way of accomplishing this tight coupling between 'parallel' hierarchies of classes? Does this pattern come up often enough to have warranted a well-known general solution? A perusal of the usual sources didn't reveal any established patterns that match this problem.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are doing is approximately correct.  You would want the members such as `reproduce` to be pure virtual, though, so the base classes cannot be created.  What is your issue with type-safety?  You don't want the `Brain` subclass and the `Body` subclass to depend on each others' types.

Comment: I *do* want the `Brain` and `Body` subclasses to depend on each-other, that is the 'tight-coupling' that I was referring to in the title. But they will typically depend on eachother in simple parallel pairs, so that a BodyWithEyes expects certain things that a BrainWithVisualCortex provides, and vice versa.

Comment: @taliesin: How closely coupled are the subclasses going to be?  Is there one `Brain` that goes with each `Body` and vice versa, or do certain `Brain` subclasses require certain `Body` subclasses (that might be abstract), or something else?

Comment: @taliesin: Please check the information on Scala virtual types and see if those match the features you want.  There seem to be some approaches for doing similar things in C++, but we can look at that more if the basic idea will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah, Scala virtual types sound like a promising lead. And yes, certain Brain subclasses will require certain Body subclasses and vice versa. A certain Brain subclass will accept the corresponding Body subclass or any of _its_ subclasses, so there there is still a more complex situation than just a 1-1 relation between Brains and Bodies (otherwise I would combine them).

Comment: Is there any progress on this question? I have a similar problem (I'm working on MRF segmentation in image processing with C++). I have found documentation on scala virtual types but I don't know how to implement that in C++.

Comment: Could you add a `BrainBodyPair` base class that has both `brain` and `body` members then define subclasses of that with more specialized member types?  You would then pass objects of that combined type around (by pointer or reference) to the functions that currently require `Brain*` or `Body*`.