# Implementing covariance using Virtual types (Abstract types)

Tags: scala, covariance, abstract-type

to ensure covariance there is three ways :

1. Pure covariance : using Eiffel language,
2. Simulating covariance : using casts and overloading
3. Using F-bounded ploymorphism OR virtual types

So I am testing the solution with virtual types, using scala Abstract types on the following example :

- We define 3 abstract classes : Graph, Node, Edge
- the Graph class defines 2 methods : attachNode(Node) and detachNode(Node)
- the Node class defines 2 methods : attachToGraph(Graph) and detachFromGraph()

Using inheretence we will create different subclasses for different domains :

- For Networks : `class Network extends Graph`, and `class Host extends Node`, ..
- For chemistry: `class Molecule extends Graph`, and `class Atom extends Node`,..
- ...

the only constraint is to avoid creating "chimera" by for example attaching an Atom to a Network. So the model is relatively simple :

```
abstract class Graph {
  type CompatibleNode <: Node
  protected var myNodes = new ArrayBuffer[CompatibleNode]()

  def attachNode(node : compatibleNode) = {
      .... 

      // Inform the node about the attachement so it can do update
      node.attachToGraph(this)

      // save the node
      myNodes += node
  }
}

abstract class Node {
  type CompatibleGraph >: scala.Null <: Graph
  protected var myGraph : CompatibleGraph = null

  def attachToGraph(graph : compatibleGraph) = {
      .... 

      // Inform the graph about the attachement so it can do update
      graph.attachNode(this)

      // save the node
      myGraph = graph
  }
}
```

And after to create special graphs we have just to override virtual types :

```
class Network extends Graph { override type CompatibleNode = Host}
class Host extends Node { override type CompatibleGraph = Network}

class Molecule extends Graph { override type CompatibleNode = Atom}
class Atom extends Node { override type CompatibleGraph = Molecule}
```

This should work well (it works in NIT language) But I had different error :

- First, type mismatch when calling `graph.attachNode(this)` this requiered `graph.CompatibleNode`, found : `Graph` , so i cast this :

  graph.attachNode(this.asInstanceOf[graph.CompatibleNode])

Note that the NIT language do that casts implicitly.

- Second, after that for detachFromGraph() method :

  class Node {

  ```
  ...

  def detachFromGraph() = {

       ....

       // inform my graph 
       myGraph.detachNode(this.asInstanceOf[myGraph.CompatibleNode])

       ...
   }
  ```

  }

I got the error : `myGraph.compatibleNode : requiered stable identifier`, and after searching and reading specifications i found that : 
-> a stable identifier is path wich end with an identifier 
-> `p.x` is a path, if `p` is a path and `x` is a stable member 
-> stable members are ..... or value definitions of non-volatile types 
-> volatile types : type parameter or abstract type, ....

So in brief i cann't use an object of abstract type in path , WHY? I don't know!

so if any one have suggestions , or even if it is possible to use scala abstract types as virtual types.

Comment: I don't see how Eiffel “ensures” covariance. Its way of handling covariance even violates the Liskov substitution principle by allowing covariant types parameters even if they are in contravariant positions.

Comment: I have read in the comments of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129943/tightly-coupled-parallel-class-hierarchies-in-c) (I have a similar problem) that it is possible to implement some of those ideas in C++. Does anybody know how?

Comment: What kind of covariance are you talking about? Maybe it would help if you could state your definition. At the moment your definitions are unsound because if you call `attachNode`, you cannot ensure that `this` is compatible with the `Node` (and v.v. for `attachToGraph`), since your type scheme does not require/express that compatibility relationships are symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

This works (and removes the infinite loop, too). The package is just to be able to illustrate package private methods.

```
package foo {
  abstract class Graph {
    type CompatibleNode <: Node
    protected var myNodes = new ArrayBuffer[CompatibleNode]()

    def attachNode(node: CompatibleNode)
                  (implicit ev: this.type <:< node.CompatibleGraph) {

      // Inform the node about the attachement so it can do update
      node.backAttach(ev(this))

      // save the node
      myNodes += node
    }

    private[foo] def backAttach(node: CompatibleNode) { myNodes += node }
  }

  abstract class Node {
    type CompatibleGraph >: scala.Null <: Graph
    protected var myGraph: CompatibleGraph = null

    def attachToGraph(graph: CompatibleGraph)
                     (implicit ev: this.type <:< graph.CompatibleNode) {

      // Inform the graph about the attachement so it can do update
      graph.backAttach(ev(this))

      // save the node
      myGraph = graph
    }

    private[foo] def backAttach(graph: CompatibleGraph) { myGraph = graph }
  }
}
```

Now:

```
class Network extends foo.Graph { override type CompatibleNode = Host}
class Host extends foo.Node { override type CompatibleGraph = Network}

class Molecule extends foo.Graph { override type CompatibleNode = Atom}
class Atom extends foo.Node { override type CompatibleGraph = Molecule}
```

And try it out:

```
object GraphTest {
  val n = new Network()
  val h = new Host()

  n.attachNode(h)

  val a = new Atom()

  n.attachNode(a) // fails: type mismatch;
  // found : Atom required: GraphTest.n.CompatibleNode (which expands to) Host
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's а workaround:

```
  def detachFromGraph () {
      detachFromThisGraph (myGraph)
  }

  def detachFromThisGraph (graph : CompatibleGraph) {
      graph.detachNode(this.asInstanceOf[graph.CompatibleNode])
  }
```

I have not a slightest idea what a stable identifier is, or why is it needed here.